# Create xorg input device configuration file for only a specific device

Tags: xorg

I've noticed that there are a few problems with using the Apple Magic Trackpad by default on Ubuntu derivatives. I've found the solution lies in making a modification to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptic.conf` (or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptic.conf`, but that file recommends that you copy and edit it at the before-mentioned `/etc` path):

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
      # Fix for trackpad sensitivity. 
      Option "VertResolution" "75"
      Option "HorizResolution" "75"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

The two trackpad resolution options above are the important ones. What I'd like to do is create a customized configuration file which *only* targets Apple Magic Trackpads and submit it as a patch upstream to make life easier for people. How can I adjust my configuration file to be more specific and only target the Apple Magic Trackpad?

Comment: Please see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find out the USB ID of the device by using `lsusb`. Add a line to your configuration after `MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"` which contains `MatchUSBID "4567:89ab"` where the last hexadecimal code is the one from `lsusb`.

See also the documentation for `xorg.conf.d(5)`.

Comment: The Apple Magic Trackpad is a Bluetooth device, so I'm not sure that I'll be able to find it in `lsusb`.

Comment: Sorry. You can probably see the Vendor/Product pair in `lsinput` then. It probably is `MatchUSBID "05ac:030e"` and should work on Bluetooth devices despite the name.

Comment: Great, so I just have a single `MatchUSBID "05ac:030e"` clause in there and that's all I need?